# In Rails, how do you get a variable that holds a database field name into a condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following controller code doesn't work. Is there a way?

```
@m = "jan"
@teams = Team.find(:all, :conditions => ["@m = ?", true], :order => "name asc")
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interpolate the string!

```
@m = "jan"
@teams = Team.find(:all, :conditions => ["#{@m} = ?", true], :order => "name asc")
```

And by the way, database queries when checking for booleans should use the IS operator

```
@m = "jan"
@teams = Team.find(:all, :conditions => ["#{@m} IS ?",true], :order => "name asc")
```

Comment: I've just tested it, and it works. Maybe it is a mysql convention and i've assumed that it is a general rule. Apologies.

Answer (score 3):

If using rails 3.x

```
@teams = Team.where(@m => true).order("name asc").all
```